# How to resolve this python migration error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, migration

Newbie Python and Django coder

I am trying to apply some migration files necessary for a registration plugin (django-registration-redux==1.3). However when I run the *python manage.py migrate* command, I receive the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "//Projects/hellowebapp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "//Projects/hellowebapp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "//Projects/hellowebapp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "//Projects/hellowebapp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "//Projects/hellowebapp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "//Projects/hellowebapp/venv/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "//Projects/hellowebapp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/registration/models.py", line 206, in <module>
    class RegistrationProfile(models.Model):
  File "//Projects/hellowebapp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/registration/models.py", line 222, in RegistrationProfile
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserModelString(), verbose_name=_('user'))
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

Not sure how to resolve this error or fully understand what it is saying.

Comment: The error is with the model, not the migration. You shouldn't be calling the related model within your OneToOneField.

Comment: The error comes from not having `on_delete` argument set on a OneToOneField Read about `on_delete` in the official docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

It's described for `ForeignKey` field but same applies to the OneToOneField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick look at the `django-registration-redux` docs (https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html), for one I would recommend updating to the latest version of this package, which is 2.5. The problem I find most of the time with this type of error has to do with the django settings, i.e. if the correct middleware was added, `INSTALLED_APPS`, etc. I hope I could help.

Comment: Thanks, installing the latest version of the package fixed the issue. And I was able to successfully execute the migration command

Comment: As a side note, I would also recommend using a virtual environment package for most django projects. Pipenv is a great library for this and keeps all of your packages up to date.